# Minimal p-value for scipy.stats.pearsonr

Tags: scipy, scipy.stats, pearson

I am running [`scipy.stats.pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) on my data, and I get

`(0.9672434106763087, 0.0)  # (r, p)`

It is reasonable that the *r*-value is high and the *p*-value is very low.
However, the true *p*-value is obviously not exactly 0, so I would like to know what `p=0.0` means. Is it `p<1e-10`, `p<1e-100`, or what is the limit?

Comment: The smallest possible 64bit floating point number is 2.225e-308 as reported by [`numpy.finfo(float)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) on my system, so your p is probably less than that. But for any practical purpose, why would you care?

Comment: Thanks. I would be surprised if it was the floating point limit that set the p value limit, though.

Comment: If it's not floating point, I have no idea what limit you are talking about. By varying the number of  samples we can obtain arbitrarily low p-values - until the floating points bite.

Comment: I guess my question is how the p-value is calculated. For example, if done using a Monte Carlo algorithm, I would not expect it to do 2.225e-308 iterations.

Comment: No, that would be very few iterations indeed :) The p-value is computed analytically. [How exactly](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3029) I'm not sure, but I think it is based on the [assumption that the data is normally distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution).

Comment: Thanks for the link, it makes sense. I guess I should have looked there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in the magnitude of p-values below the floating point minimum, you can use `mpmath`.

The [`pearsonr` documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) states that the two-sided p-value is given by.

```py
dist = scipy.stats.beta(n/2 - 1, n/2 - 1, loc=-1, scale=2)
p = 2*dist.cdf(-abs(r))
```

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), the CDF of the beta distribution is the [regularized incomplete beta function](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/gamma.html#betainc).

Putting it together:

```py
from mpmath import mp
mp.dps = 1000

r = mp.mpf(0.9672434106763087)
n = 1000

x = (-abs(r) + 1)/2  # shift per `loc=-1`, scale per `scale=2`
p = 2*mp.betainc(n/2 - 1, n/2 - 1, 0, x, regularized=True)
# 1.534373680362601e-596
```

If you want to stick with floating point arithmetic, you'll have to work in log-space. Unfortunately, the log of the regularized incomplete beta function is not implemented in SciPy, but you can compute the log of the regularized incomplete beta function from the log of the integrand using quadrature.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate._tanhsinh import _tanhsinh
from scipy import special

r = 0.9672434106763087
n = 1000

x = (-abs(r) + 1)/2 
a = b = n/2 - 1
def logf(t):
    # log of incomplete beta function integrand
    return (a-1)*np.log(t) + (b-1)*np.log1p(-t)

# multiplying by 2 -> adding log(2)
# regularization / dividing by beta(a, b) -> subtracting betaln(a, b)
_tanhsinh(logf, 0, x, log=True).integral + np.log(2) - special.betaln(a, b)
# -1371.9125931524995  # log(1.534373680362601e-596)
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @MB-F in the comments it is calculated analytically.

In the code for the version [0.19.1](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.19.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3029), you could isolate that part of the code and plot the p-value in terms of `r`

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import betainc
r = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)*(1-1e-10);

for n in [10, 100, 1000]:
    df = n - 2
    t_squared = r**2 * (df / ((1.0 - r) * (1.0 + r)))
    prob = betainc(0.5*df, 0.5, df/(df+t_squared))
    plt.semilogy(r, prob, label=f'n={n}')
plt.axvline(0.9672434106763087, ls='--', color='black', label='r value')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

[image]

The current stable version [1.9.3](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.9.3/scipy/stats/_stats_py.py#L4480) uses a different formula

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.special import btdtr
r = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)*(1-1e-10);
for n in [10, 100, 1000]:
    ab = 0.5*n
    prob = btdtr(ab, ab, 0.5*(1-abs(r)))
    plt.semilogy(r, prob, label=f'n={n}')
plt.axvline(0.9672434106763087, ls='--', color='black', label='r value')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

But yield the same results.

You can see that if you have 1000 points and your correlation, the `p` value will be less than the minimum floating value.

#### The beta distribution

Scipy provides a collection of [probability distributions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions), among them, the [beta distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html#scipy.stats.beta).

The line

```py
    prob = btdtr(ab, ab, 0.5*(1-abs(r)))
```

could be replaced by

```
from scipy.stats import beta
prob = beta(ab, ab).cdf(0.5*(1-abs(r)))
```

There you can get much more information about it.